# .Net WebSocket Unable To Connect Remote Server Error

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

I made a WebSocket Application with a Console Application. I divided it into two as Client and Server, but when I run the application I get the error " Unable to connect to web server "WebSocketCore". The web server is no longer running."

WebSocket.Server :

```
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace WebSocketCore.Server
{
    public class Program
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        }
            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
            {
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                }

                app.UseRouting();
                var wsOptions = new WebSocketOptions { KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120) };
                app.UseWebSockets(wsOptions);
                app.Use(async (context, next) =>
                {
                    await next.Invoke();
                    if (context.Request.Path == "/send")
                    {
                        if (context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
                        {
                            using (WebSocket webSocket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync())
                            {
                                await Send(context, webSocket);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
        private async Task Send(HttpContext context, WebSocket webSocket)
            {
                var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
                WebSocketReceiveResult result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
                if (result != null)
                {
                    while (!result.CloseStatus.HasValue)
                    {
                        string msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, result.Count));
                        Console.WriteLine($"client says: {msg}");
                        await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"Server says: {DateTime.UtcNow:f}")), result.MessageType, result.EndOfMessage, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
                        result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
                        // Console.WriteLine(result);

                    }
                }
                await webSocket.CloseAsync(result.CloseStatus.Value, result.CloseStatusDescription, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
            }
        }
    }
```

WebSocket.Client :

```
using System;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Text;

namespace Ws.Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Devam Etmek İçin Bir Tuşa Basın...");
            Console.ReadLine();

            using (ClientWebSocket client = new ClientWebSocket())
            {
                Uri serviceUri = new Uri("ws://localhost:5000/send");
                var cTs = new CancellationTokenSource();
                cTs.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
                try
                {
                    await client.ConnectAsync(serviceUri, cTs.Token);
                    var n = 0;
                    while (client.State == WebSocketState.Open)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Mesaj Giriniz");
                        string message = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
                        {
                            ArraySegment<byte> byteToSend = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
                            await client.SendAsync(byteToSend, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, cTs.Token);
                            var responseBuffer = new byte[1024];
                            var offset = 0;
                            var packet = 1024;
                            while (true)
                            {
                                ArraySegment<byte> byteReceived = new ArraySegment<byte>(responseBuffer, offset, packet);
                                WebSocketReceiveResult response = await client.ReceiveAsync(byteReceived, cTs.Token);
                                var responseMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBuffer, offset, response.Count);
                                Console.WriteLine(responseMessage);
                                if (response.EndOfMessage)
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (WebSocketException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to fix but i can't.

Comment: `public static void Main(string[] args) { }` isn't going to do anything, so not surprising. Perhaps you wanted an ASP.Net `Main` function

Comment: when i delete it it gives this error "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point"

Comment: Yes, but leaving it completely empty means nothing is going to run. You need to put some *actual code* in it to make the application do something, such as setting up an ASP.Net server

Comment: so what should i do now for solution?

Comment: Maybe this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=windows#programcs